# Accessing Rails environment config in Rake namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rakefile

I have a path defined in my `environment.rb` file

```
MyRailsApp::Application.configure do
  config.xml_import_path = "/path/to/xml"
end
```

I'd like to be able to set a variableaccess these within a Rake file like this

```
namespace :myapp do
  xml_path = MyRailsApp::Application.config.xml_import_path

  task :first_task => :environment do
    # do some stuff with xml_path
  end

  task :second_task => :environment do
    # do some other stuff with xml_path
  end
end
```

but I keep getting an error when I run `rake myapp:first_task`

```
undefined method `xml_import_path' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000006a98bd8>
```

I guess it's something to do with the environment no being loaded, as it works if I put

```
xml_path = MyRailsApp::Application.config.xml_import_path
```

inside the task definition.

Is there any way to use config values set in `environment.rb` like I am attempting to do?

Is there a better/right way to do it?

cheers,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use config values set in `environment.rb` like I am attempting to do?

yes you can load your Rails Environment into any script

just add

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
```

before you call the variable you want to call

however, the best way to load the environment in your case is to add the above code to the `bin/rake` file or the `config/boot.rb` one

reference: https://shifteleven.com/articles/2006/10/08/loading-your-rails-environment-into-a-script/

Another way is to use the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) and save the path in the `.env` the file then load that var in your `environment.rb` and `rake` file